# LINQ Lambda Summing NULL

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am using LINQ to objects to sum the values within two objects and return one single version of the object with the summed totals.

The problem I am having is that the LINQ sum function is summing NULLs as zero (0).  I would expect that if I had one value of say "15" and the other value as "null", that the sum should be "15".  But I would expect that if the first value was "null" and the second value was "null", that the sum should also be "null".  However, it is telling me that the sum is "0".

How can I get it to function as I would expect?  I want it to behave by returning a value if there is at least one value or return "null" if there are no values.

Now for some code:

```
virtual public IStatSplit Totals
{
  get
  {
    var cSplit = _splits.Where(s => s.Split == SplitType.COMBINED).SingleOrDefault();

    if( cSplit != null )
    { return cSplit; }

    cSplit = _splits.Where( s => s.Split != SplitType.COMBINED )
                    .GroupBy( g => 1 == 1 ).Select( x => new StatSplit
    {
      AB = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.AB ),
      CI = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.CI ),
      B2 = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.B2 ),
      B3 = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.B3 ),
      GDP = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.GDP ),
      H = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.H ),
      HB = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.HB ),
      HR = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.HR ),
      RBI = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.RBI ),
      IBB = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.IBB ),
      SF = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.SF ),
      SH = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.SH ),
      SO = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.SO ),
      BB = (uint?)x.Sum( q => q.BB ),
      Split = SplitType.COMBINED
    } ).SingleOrDefault();

    return cSplit;
  }
}
```

And here is the test data that will not pass a unit test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PitchingTotals()
{
  var splits = GetSplits();
  var pitching = new Base.Pitching();
  pitching.Splits = splits;

  var expected = GetTotalSplit();
  var result = pitching.Totals;

  // result.RBI = 0
  // expected.RBI = null
  // this fails because the "0" is not expected

  Assert.AreEqual( expected, result );
}

private List<IStatSplit> GetSplits()
{
  var lhSplit = new Base.StatSplit
  {
    AB = 442,
    H = 97,
    B2 = 14,
    B3 = 0,
    HR = 6,
    BB = 28,
    HB = 6,
    SF = 1,
    SH = 5,
    SO = 73,
    GDP = 7,
    IBB = 4,
    CI = 0,
    RBI = null,
    Split = Enumerations.SplitType.VS_LEFT
  };

  var rhSplit = new Base.StatSplit
  {
    AB = 633,
    H = 101,
    B2 = 9,
    B3 = 0,
    HR = 5,
    BB = 34,
    HB = 1,
    SF = 1,
    SH = 10,
    SO = 195,
    GDP = 11,
    IBB = 2,
    CI = 0,
    RBI = null,
    Split = Enumerations.SplitType.VS_RIGHT
  };

  List<IStatSplit> splits = new List<IStatSplit>();
  splits.Add( lhSplit );
  splits.Add( rhSplit );

  return splits;
}

private IStatSplit GetTotalSplit()
{
  var split = new Base.StatSplit
  {
    AB = 1075,
    H = 198,
    B2 = 23,
    B3 = 0,
    HR = 11,
    BB = 62,
    HB = 7,
    SF = 2,
    SH = 15,
    SO = 268,
    GDP = 18,
    IBB = 6,
    CI = 0,
    RBI = null,
    Split = Enumerations.SplitType.COMBINED
  };

  return split;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `Sum` you can use [`Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549218(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
x.Aggregate(
    (uint?)null,
    (sum, currentItem) => 
        !sum.HasValue && !currentItem.AB.HasValue ? 
        (uint?)null : 
        sum.GetValueOrDefault() + currentItem.AB.GetValueOrDefault());
```

This will start with a `null` `uint?` value and iterate through each item.  If the current `sum` and value `currentItem.AB` are both `null` then the next `sum` will continue to be `null`. If either is not `null` then they are added and the default value is used if one is `null`, which for `uint` is 0.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should write your own "SumOrNull" extension method that can return your "uint?" in the situation you described (null + null = null). The existing Linq Sum method only returns a number which is non-nullable.

[Linq Sum documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534734%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: This is not true.  In the very same link you reference it shows plenty of overloads for Sum that will return a nullable data type.  [Enumerable.Sum Method (IEnumerable<Nullable<Int32>>)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb156065(v=vs.100).aspx)  It even states that, "This method returns zero if source contains no elements."

Comment: LOL, it also states, "The result does not include values that are null."  I don't know why then the return type would be nullable if it never intends to return a null.

Comment: @ELMOJO I assumed it returns a nullable because it would return null for an empty collection, but it returns 0 in that case as well.  I guess they just wanted to keep the return type the same as the type that is being summed.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon Juharr's response, I first tried this:

```
cSplit = _splits.Where( s => s.Split != SplitType.COMBINED )
    .GroupBy( g => 1 == 1 ).Select( x => new StatSplit
    {
      AB = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.AB.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.AB.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      CI = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.CI.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.CI.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      B2 = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.B2.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.B2.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      B3 = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.B3.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.B3.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      GDP = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.GDP.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.GDP.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      H = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.H.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.H.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      HB = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.HB.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.HB.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      HR = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.HR.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.HR.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      RBI = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.RBI.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.RBI.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      IBB = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.IBB.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.IBB.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      SF = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.SF.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.SF.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      SH = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.SH.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.SH.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      SO = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.SO.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.SO.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      BB = x.Aggregate( (uint?)null, ( sum, item ) => !sum.HasValue && !item.BB.HasValue ?
            (uint?)null : sum.GetValueOrDefault() + item.BB.GetValueOrDefault() ),
      Split = SplitType.COMBINED
    } ).SingleOrDefault();
```

This worked but it looked ugly to me.  I did a little bit of refining and came up with this:

```
cSplit = _splits.Aggregate( new StatSplit() { Split = SplitType.COMBINED },
    ( sum, item ) =>
    {
      sum.AB = !sum.AB.HasValue && !item.AB.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.AB.GetValueOrDefault() + item.AB.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.CI = !sum.CI.HasValue && !item.CI.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.CI.GetValueOrDefault() + item.CI.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.B2 = !sum.B2.HasValue && !item.B2.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.B2.GetValueOrDefault() + item.B2.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.B3 = !sum.B3.HasValue && !item.B3.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.B3.GetValueOrDefault() + item.B3.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.GDP = !sum.GDP.HasValue && !item.GDP.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.GDP.GetValueOrDefault() + item.GDP.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.H = !sum.H.HasValue && !item.H.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.H.GetValueOrDefault() + item.H.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.HB = !sum.HB.HasValue && !item.HB.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.HB.GetValueOrDefault() + item.HB.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.HR = !sum.HR.HasValue && !item.HR.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.HR.GetValueOrDefault() + item.HR.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.RBI = !sum.RBI.HasValue && !item.RBI.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.RBI.GetValueOrDefault() + item.RBI.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.IBB = !sum.IBB.HasValue && !item.IBB.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.IBB.GetValueOrDefault() + item.IBB.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.SF = !sum.SF.HasValue && !item.SF.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.SF.GetValueOrDefault() + item.SF.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.SH = !sum.SH.HasValue && !item.SH.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.SH.GetValueOrDefault() + item.SH.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.SO = !sum.SO.HasValue && !item.SO.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.SO.GetValueOrDefault() + item.SO.GetValueOrDefault();
      sum.BB = !sum.BB.HasValue && !item.BB.HasValue ? (uint?)null : sum.BB.GetValueOrDefault() + item.BB.GetValueOrDefault();
      return sum;
    } );
```

The first one ran in about 12ms with only two items within the list.  The refined second one ran in about 9ms with only two items within the list.  I am going with the second entry because it is more efficient and also looks cleaner and is easier to follow.  Thanks to Juharr for the push in the right direction!